# Developing a simple Course Management System for iPhone using Xcode using Table Views only

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have to build a **Course management** app. I am using table views only for this app. Using the table view controllers.

The first view contains the semesters - 1,2,3,4....12.

The second view contains details that are respective to the previous table view controller.

The details in the second table view controller are: Lectures, Papers, To-do list, Record lecture.

Depending on the user's selection, he can access Lectures, Papers, List, Record Lecture for that particular semester.
I am not able to figure out how to pass data from the third view to the fourth and subsequent views. For eg. Lecture->Lecture 1: Introduction->Download PDF.

How do I assign a specific table view controller when the user taps a particular cell? using `seques` or `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

I am confused.
Kindly help me in this regard. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will do that in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Here you prepare the view you want to present and push it into the your `navigationController`. For instance:

```
// On user tap, present the details you want. 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

}
```

Additionally, these are some relevant links for what you are trying accomplish:

-[Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html)

-[Table Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: @Alex Great! if this was the information you were looking for, you can selected as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do the selection part in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: I just want to display static information. Will the above method be able to do that? also, what is the difference between the above method and a segue?

Comment: this method will help u to give a selection to each cell of yours and remember that in cellForRowAtIndexPath we just describe act how the table view looks and in didSelect we tell why will happen if we selec a particular cell.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

Comment: go through the above link for more info on tableView